# Can't invoke DLL function without debug point

Tags: c#, dll, msmq

I have created a DLL in `C#` which creates message queue and object and send that object 
to message queue. I added the reference of the created DLL to another application. Application 
runs successfully when debug point is applied to DLL invoking function. But without debug point, it doesn't send object to message queue.

DLL Function as follows :

```
public void Enqueue()
{
    try
    {
        this.CreateQueue(); //function that creates queue
        Message msg = new Message();

        DataTable dtOrd;
        if (IsSingleOrder)
        {
            dtOrd = objDBTrans.funcGetNewOrdSingleDetails(this.DefaultSecurityCode, this.OrderCode, this.CreatedDate);
        }
        else
        {
            dtOrd = objDBTrans.funcGetBasketOrdDetails(this.DefaultSecurityCode, this.CreatedDate);
        }

        for (int iRows = 0; iRows < dtOrd.Rows.Count; iRows++)
        {
            DataRow drOrd;
            drOrd = dtOrd.Rows[iRows];                    
            objEMSOrdMap.funcAssignMapping(drOrd);
            msg.Body = objEms;
            msg.Label = strFileNamq + "_" + objEms.ClOrdID + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            queue.Send(msg);
        }        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }       
}
```

DLL function that creates queue :

```
public void CreateQueue()
{
    try
    {
        MessageQueue queue;
        queue = new MessageQueue(msgQueue, false); //msgQueue = String containing queue name          
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Application function that invoke DLL function :

```
using EMSMsmqDll;
class EMSMSMQDemo : clsDBConnection
{
    public void funcDemo()
    {
        MSMQService objSer = new MSMQService(); //Class from EMSMsmqDll that creates message queue and object and send that object to message queue
        objSer.Enqueue();
    }
}
```

Comment: So when funcDemo finishes and objser goes out of scope, what happens?

Comment: objser is object of class MSMQService of EMSMsmqDll DLL. When debug point is applied to objser.Enqueue() fuction, object gets created and send to the message queue.Without applying debug point, the object don't get send to the message queue.

Comment: Where is the `queue` variable used in `Enqueue()` defined? Where is it initialised? And I see empty `catch` blocks. I hope they aren't in your real code!

Comment: Hmm was a rhetorical question, objser goes out of scope when funcDemo completes...